# Substitute NAs by value present in grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr, na

## Fake data

```
fruit <- c("Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana")
flavour <- c("Bitter", NA, NA, "Sweet")
geo <- c(NA, NA, NA, "France")
value <- c(1, NA, NA, 4)
dd <- data.frame(fruit, flavour, geo, value)
rm(fruit, flavour, geo, value)
```

[image]

I'd like to group the dataset by 'fruit' and substitute the missing values
in all variables with the value present in the grouped data.

## Desired output

```
fruit <- c("Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana")
flavour <- c("Bitter", "Sweet", "Bitter", "Sweet")
geo <- c(NA, "France", NA, "France")
value <- c(1, 4, 1, 4)
dd2 <- data.frame(fruit, flavour, geo, value)
rm(fruit, flavour, geo, value)
```

[image]

## Code attempt

```
tt <- dd %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  summarise_all()
```

Comment: An base R option: `dd$flavour <- with(dd, ave(flavour, fruit, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))`.

Comment: What do you want to do if there are more than one non-NA values in a group?

Comment: It's not likely to happen in my data. But if variable was numeric I'd like to do average and if it is character I'd ideally concatenate the possible values. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need `mutate_all` after the `group_by` (`summarise/summarise_all` is used to get a single row from multiple rows).  Use `na.locf` from `zoo` to fill the NA elements with the adjacent non-NA elements for each column

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(fruit) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(na.locf(na.locf(., na.rm =  FALSE), 
                 fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   fruit [2]
#  fruit  flavour geo    value
#  <fct>  <fct>   <fct>  <dbl>
#1 Orange Bitter  <NA>       1
#2 Banana Sweet   France     4
#3 Orange Bitter  <NA>       1
#4 Banana Sweet   France     4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I get an error because one of my entries only has NAs. See edits.

Comment: @user3262756  Updated the post.  Hope it helps

Comment: The solution works, but I get this warning message: Warning messages:
1: In na.locf.default(., flavour, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE) :
  na.locf.default: rev= deprecated. Use fromLast= instead.

Comment: @user3262756  That looks like a friendly warning.

Comment: @user3262756  Now, you can check whether the warning is there.  I think the `%>%` within the `funs` triggered the warning though it has not much impact on the final outcome

Answer (score 1):

I created a function to do exactly this. It relies on dplyr::coalesce.
It will only fill the values if all values in the group are equal. it's also possible to specify a minimum (n or Percentage) of known values, to prevent a single value to fill all values in a group

```
library(dplyr)
fill_missing <- function (x, min_known_n = NULL, min_known_p = NULL) {
    if (NA %in% x) {
        y <- na.omit(x)
        y_n_distinct <- length(unique(y))
        if (!is.null(min_known_n)) {
            known_n <- length(y)
            if (known_n < min_known_n) {
                return(x)
            }
        }
        if (!is.null(min_known_p)) {
            known_p <- length(y)/length(x)
            if (known_p < min_known_p) {
                return(x)
            }
        }
        if (y_n_distinct == 1) {
            x <- dplyr::coalesce(x, y[1])
        }

    }
    return(x)
}

dd %>% group_by(fruit) %>% 
    mutate_all(fill_missing)
```

Comment: Really nice solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've put the function in the `fillr` package to do this with the function `fill_missing_strict`. its on CRAN https://jelger12.github.io/fillr/